# Access Access Database located in Virtual Directory

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP application deployed on a web server.
I have a separate File Share for which I have created a virtual directory from the web server.
I need to keep all my access db in the file share.

In the connection string if I try to provide the Datasource as http://abc.web.boe.com/def/TEST/database/prototype.mdb, it is not able to access the MDB file.

I get the following error:
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
Not a valid file name.

Is it some kind of permission issue or is not possible to use http url path for data source?

Comment: as data source you should provide path to file, not url as in your sample

Comment: you could try to create and use DSN link/connection to database, which are located on different server in your network.

Comment: You cannot use http: in path name.  You don't connect to Excel, or connect to word, or in this case Access. The Access file is a plane jane file sitting on the hard drive. You can no more connect to a Access file then that of connecting to a text file. You thus require and will be  using the windows standard file open command. Such commands don't work over FTP or HTTP for that matter. So you going to open a WINDOWS file. Any connection string specified MUST resolve and be a standard windows file path and support the windows file system. Connection string MUST always be a UNC path name.

Comment: If I have to provide a windows file share name, then will all the users accessing the application need to be provided access to File Share.

Comment: if you want to share the database, you could try Share-point List